# How to store a matrix

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working with a big matrix

```
var counterMatrix1 = Array(heroCount + 1, {DoubleArray(heroCount + 1)})
```

I need to save it to a db and load it. What do you think is the best method to do this. any suggestions?

Comment: Serialize eveything with a ObjectOutputStream is the easier way

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this would be done in Kotlin, but in Java I would make a Matrix class and have it wrap around my array object (I'm assuming you have a 2d matrix, but the same idea applies with a different matrix). Then use the Gson library to convert it to JSON, and save your JSON string to the DB. To get it back from the DB into its Matrix object from the DB, use Gson again to deserialize it. Here's an example:

```
public class Matrix {

    public CustomObject[][] = new CustomObject[r][c]; //where r and c can be any value for capacity

}
```

Then do this when you are about to save your Matrix to your DB:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

//Do stuff with your matrix, add data to it, etc..

//Then save it your DB

Gson gson = new Gson();
String matrixJson = gson.toJson(matrix);

saveMatrixJsonToDB(matrixJson);
```

To load it back from DB I would do this:

```
public void loadMatrixFromDB(/*any params to connect to DB*/) {
    String matrixJson;
    //Connect to db and retrieve your matrix json string that you previously saved...

    //Then convert it back to the Java object
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Matrix matrix = gson.fromJson(matrixJson, Matrix.class);
}
```

Comment: Same answer as the first one above, if you have something to add please edit the other one.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos They are pretty different since I provide the the complete Java and Gson code examples. Why would I edit his answer?

Comment: Aren't you offering the same solution?

Comment: Yes but I provide a code example and it's clearer in my opinion. If I modified his, he would get the credit.

Comment: before I asked the question I have tried to save it in a SQL table row/column/value, so each row of the sql table was a cell of my matrix. When I was saving the matrix I used a nested for, when loading I did just go over every row of the table and update the value in my matrix. Loading was a lot faster then saving. the matrix is just huge! loading took about 20 sec saving about 3 min. I was thinking maybe I can transform it to something like a blob or bytes. I am not sure json would be a lot faster than my method.

Answer (score -1):

You can save this array in json format, and after that you can serialize this back to an array.

for example:

```
int[] NumberList=new int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

is a one dimensional array and in json format it looks like:

```
{  "NumberList" : [1,2,3,4,5,6] }
```

Comment: Save JSON to DB:
String json = NumberList.toString();
//and insert this string into DB.
Read json from DB:
String json = Read_column_value_logic_here
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

Comment: before I asked the question I have tried to save it in a SQL table row/column/value, so each row of the sql table was a cell of my matrix. When I was saving the matrix I used a nested for, when loading I did just go over every row of the table and update the value in my matrix. Loading was a lot faster then saving. the matrix is just huge! loading took about 20 sec saving about 3 min. I was thinking maybe I can transform it to something like a blob or bytes. I am not sure json would be a lot faster than my method.

Comment: when you update array saved in Json, you update(in table) just one row, but when you update array with your method, you update(in table) multiple rows,  that's why saving takes a long time

Comment: but still is there a faster way?

Comment: in Xamarin.android is happening pretty quickly, and if I would do that I think I would still use my method.